# Android Room store map field as a table

Tags: android, android-room

having a class with map field, can i tell Room to store the map field in a connected table?

for example, having :

```
@Entity
class A {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    private Map<String, String> b;
}
```

Id expect it to create table a, and a_b, where a = [id] and a_b=[a_id,key,value], a_b primary key would be composite of fields [a_id,key] and the rows will be updated in correspondence to map actions. is there something already implemented i could use? if not any lead on how to do it right?

I also consider the alternative of using a typeconverter on the map and serialize/deserialize the map to string but i dont like it because:

1. the string may be too big, hard to tell what length should be used for the column
2. redundant serializing and deserializing may hurt performance (although its hard to tell if the alternative joins is more performant)

Interesting to hear more opinions around it

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Room is a wrapper around SQLite and as such a column (field/member) of an @Entity (table) must be either an integer type value, a text/String type value, a decimal type value, a byte stream type value or null. Objects including Arrays/Maps/Lists cannot be stored directly.

Arrays/Maps/Lists can be stored if converted to one of the types that can be stored, which really limits the resultant data/value to a String or a bytestream.

As such you either need a TypeConverter

- 2 one for converting from the Object to the type (typically a JSON representation as a String) and another for converting the stored type to the result Object.

Or you can use a related table (or tables for say objects that have embedded objects).

The former (Type Conversion) is typically simpler BUT the stored data (e.g. JSON String) will very likely contain bloat (other data that allows the conversion to be reversed) and can introduce complexities and inefficiencies if that data were used for selecting data.

The latter utilises the fact that SQLite is a relational database and as such is designed to handle related data, the overhead would typically be a single column for a one-one or one-many relationship that identifies the parent/owner. For a many-many relationship then an intermediate table with two columns (one to say which A is related and another to say which B is related). The additional overhead, is that such columns should probably be indexed which allows more optimal retrieval of the data. Another advantage is that the data is stored as is and using that data as a selection criteria is simpler than selecting part of a converted value.

**Examples**

Trying to use :-

```
@Entity
class A {
   @PrimaryKey
   long id;
   private Map<String, String> b;
}
```

- Note with an `@Database` annotated Class (TheDatabase in this case) that includes `A.class` as one of the classes (the only class in this case) in the `entities` parameter of the annotation e.g. `@Database(entities = {A.class}, exportSchema = false,version = 1)`
- **The build fails** with `error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. private Map<String, String> b;`

To overcome this a TypeConverter pair can be used. A TypeConverter pair has to be in a class that is made know to Room via the `@TypeConverters` annotation.

So a new Class `RoomTypeConverters` could be (note com.google.code.gson dependency added):-

```
class RoomTypeConverters {

   @TypeConverter
   public String convertFromMapToJSONString(Map<String,String> theMap) {
      return new Gson().toJson(theMap);
   }
   @TypeConverter
   public Map<String,String> convertFromJSONStringToMap(String jsonString) {
      return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,Map.class);
   }
}
```

With a few tweaks (getters and setters added) and the annotation `@TypeConverters({RoomTypeConverters.class})` being added to the `@Database` annotated Class (highest scope, can be added elsewhere) then the build works.

**Store and retrieve some data**

First another abstract class (or interface is added) annotated with @Dao for the functions to store and retrieve the data.

- an abstract class allows functions with bodies so is more flexible. However, you have to have the abstract keyword to the functions to be used by Room.

So `AllDao` is added :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(A a);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM A WHERE b LIKE('%'||:searchFor||'%')")
    abstract List<A> getAllFromAWithSearchItem(String searchFor);

}
```

- **Actually running this will be dealt with later**

**An Equivalent using a second table**

To compare one against the other an AA class is created, like the A class but without b (hardly any use as it's just the id column, but ok for demo).:-

```
@Entity
class AA {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
}
```

To facilitate the second table for the equivalent of the embedded Map then class AAMap:-

```
@Entity
class AAMap {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id=null;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long AAReference;
    String mapKey;
    String mapValue;
    AAMap(){}
    @Ignore
    AAMap(String mapKey, String mapValue, long AAReference) {
        this.mapKey = mapKey;
        this.mapValue = mapValue;
        this.AAReference = AAReference;
    }
}
```

- you would not want the primaryKey to be the reference as then an AA could only have 1 AAMap as the primary key must be unique.
- Long id=null allows the id to be generated without using the less efficient `autogenerate=true` as part of the `@PrimaryKey` annotation.
- AAReference is the column that references the parent/owning AA.
- AAReference column is indexed so access can be more efficient

Now to facilitate extracting an AA with the related AAMaps then a POJO class AAWithAAMAps :-

```
class AAWithAAMaps {
   @Embedded
   AA theAA;
   @Relation(entity = AAMap.class, parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "AAReference")
   List<AAMap> theAAMapList;
}
```

- The @Embedded basically copies the members of the embedded class.
- The @Relation annotation tells room about the relationship.
- Note that as there can be 0 to n related AAMaps the member is a List

To faciltate a working example that compares the two approaches AllDao becomes:-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(A a);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM A")
    abstract List<A> getAllFromA();
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(AA aa);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(AAMap aaMap);
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM AA")
    abstract List<AAWithAAMaps> getAllAAsWithRelatedAAMaps();
}
```

The @Database annotated class `TheDatabase` that ties this all together is:-

```
@TypeConverters({RoomTypeConverters.class})
@Database(entities = {A.class,AA.class,AAMap.class}, exportSchema = false,version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
   abstract AllDao getAllDao();

   private volatile static TheDatabase instance;
   public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance==null) {
         instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database")
                 .allowMainThreadQueries()
                 .build();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

- main thread used for convenience and brevity.

Finally some Activity code `MainActivity` that will insert and extract the same core data for each approach using:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();
        
        /* Approach 1 - Map  converted*/

        Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.id = 200;
        m.put("KEY1","TOM");
        m.put("KEY2","MARY");
        m.put("KEY3","JANE");
        m.put("KEY4","BERT");
        m.put("KEY5","ALICE");
        m.put("KEY6","ALAN");
        a1.setB(m);
        long a1Id = dao.insert(a1);
        /* Extract the data */
        for (A a: dao.getAllFromA()) {
            Map currentM = a.getB();
            Log.d("DBDATA1","ID is " + a.id+ " Map is " + a.getB());
        }

        /* Approach 2 - one-many relationship*/
        long aa1id = dao.insert(new AA()); /* Add the parent AA (note getting the id for the related AAMaps) */ 
        /* Add the related AAMaps */
        dao.insert(new AAMap("KEY1","TOM",aa1id));
        dao.insert(new AAMap("KEY2","MARY",aa1id));
        dao.insert(new AAMap("KEY3","JANE",aa1id));
        dao.insert(new AAMap("KEY4","BERT",aa1id));
        dao.insert(new AAMap("KEY5","ALICE",aa1id));
        dao.insert(new AAMap("KEY6","ALAN",aa1id));
        /* Extract the data */
        for (AAWithAAMaps aawm: dao.getAllAAsWithRelatedAAMaps()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (AAMap am: aawm.theAAMapList) {
                sb.append("\n\tKey is " + am.mapKey + " Value is " + am.mapValue + " it references AA with ID " + am.AAReference);
            }
            Log.d("DBDATA2","ID is " + aawm.theAA.id + ". It has " + aawm.theAAMapList.size() + " AAMaps. They are." + sb);
        }
    }
}
```

When run from a fresh install, then output sent to the log :-

```
D/DBDATA1: ID is 200 Map is {KEY2=MARY, KEY1=TOM, KEY6=ALAN, KEY5=ALICE, KEY4=BERT, KEY3=JANE}


D/DBDATA2: ID is 0. It has 6 AAMaps. They are.
        Key is KEY1 Value is TOM it references AA with ID 0
        Key is KEY2 Value is MARY it references AA with ID 0
        Key is KEY3 Value is JANE it references AA with ID 0
        Key is KEY4 Value is BERT it references AA with ID 0
        Key is KEY5 Value is ALICE it references AA with ID 0
        Key is KEY6 Value is ALAN it references AA with ID 0
```

So the stored data is basically the same (looping through the map omitted for convenience/brevity).

However, looking at the actual data in the database (via App Inspection) then:-

Table A (Approach 1) is:-

[image]

Whilst for Approach 2 table AA is:-

[image]

And table AAMap is:-

[image]

> Interesting to hear more opinions around it

> the string may be too big, hard to tell what length should be used for the column

You don't have to define the length of columns. However, there is a limitation in that underneath it all Room uses the Android API's Cursor to extract data. The data is buffered into/via a CursorWindow. A CursorWindow is restricted in size (1-4Mb depending on the Android versions). And has to accommodate entire rows, so if any row is larger than the CursorWindow limit then an exception will occur.

> redundant serializing and deserializing may hurt performance (although its hard to tell if the alternative joins is more performant)

Still hard to tell BUT SQLite is designed to be used in this way. However Room's approach when using @Relation, in that it extracts the children via an additional underlying query (hence why @Trasnaction is used) is perhaps not the most efficient (A single query with JOINS could get all the data, but then the children have to be built from the cartesian product)

As far opinions, the above may allow you to form your own.

Comment: @MileT please can you help me with one question about room typeconverter?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785064/how-to-make-room-typeconerter-return-correct-object-not-a-linkedtreemap