# How to make ROOM TypeConerter return correct object not a LinkedTreeMap?

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, types, android-room

I have such entity class

```
@Entity
data class ListResponse(
    @SerializedName("answer")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "answer")
    val answer: Map<Int, ItemList>
)
 
data class ItemList(
    @SerializedName("yes")
    val yes: YesItem,
 
    @SerializedName("no")
    val no: NoItem
)
 
data class YesItem(
    @SerializedName("time")
    val timeYes: String,
 
    @SerializedName("date")
    val dateYes: String
)
 
data class NoItem(
    @SerializedName("time")
    val timeNo: String,
 
    @SerializedName("date")
    val dateNo: String
)
```

And TypeConerter

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromMapToJSONString(map: Map<Int, ItemList>): String {
        return Gson().toJson(promotionMap)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromJSONStringToMap(jsonString: String?): Map<Int, ItemList>? {
        return Gson().fromJson<Map<Int, ItemList>>(jsonString, MutableMap::class.java)
    }
```

Repository Class

```
    suspend fun insert(respone: ListResponse) {
        dao.insert(respone)
    }

    suspend fun getAll(): ListResponse {
        return dao.getAll()
    }
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ListDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(list: ListResponse): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME")
    suspend fun getAll(): ListResponse

    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "list_table"
    }
}
```

But class live data liveData.getValue() return LinkedTreeMap, not ListResponse object
but if I do

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().toJsonTree(liveData.getValue()).getAsJsonObject();
ListResponse reedUnreadItemList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, ListResponse.class);
```

It will return correct ListResponse object.

How cant I put this toJsonTree to TypeConverter class, to make liveData.getValue() return correct object?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the **`getAll`** function from the `@Dao` annotated interface, as that determines what is retrieved.

Comment: @MikeT dao added